# dbeaver SQL Server select datetime column

Tags: sql-server, dbeaver

I've tried to query a SQL Server using dbeaver, but I don't know what is wrong. My system is an Ubuntu 17 64-bit, and dbeaver 4.1.2.

I can connect to the database, navigate through tables, and most of queries I did were successful.

But when I try to query a datetime column, I got these:

With `>=`:

```
select date_field from mydb where date_field >= '2018-01-01';   => ok, shows results
select date_field from mydb where date_field >= '2018-01';   => Ok, shows results
select date_field from mydb where date_field >= '2018';   => Ok, shows results
```

with `=`:

```
select date_field from mydb where date_field = '2018-01-01';   => query runs w/o errors, but shows nothing
select date_field from mydb where date_field = '2018-01-01 00:00:00';   => query runs w/o errors, but shows nothing
select date_field from mydb where date_field = '2018-01-01 any:time:sec';   => query runs w/o errors, but shows nothing, even I copy and paste full date from '>=' query
```

With `LIKE`:

```
select date_field from mydb where date_field like '2018-01-01%';   => query runs w/o errors, but shows nothing
select date_field from mydb where date_field like '%2018-01-01%';   => query runs w/o errors, but shows nothing
select date_field from mydb where date_field like '2018-01%';   => query runs w/o errors, but shows nothing
select date_field from mydb where date_field like '%2018-01%';   => query runs w/o errors, but shows nothing
select date_field from mydb where date_field like '2018%';   => query runs w/o errors, but shows nothing
select date_field from mydb where date_field like '%2018%';   => OK, shows results
```

I've not tried other statements (between, in) yet. But anyone have already faced this?

Thanks!

Comment: You say you're getting an error - what's the error? Can you post the table schema (field definitions)?

Comment: With '='

Are there any datetimes which match the values you are searching for EXACTLY?

Comment: I'm going to edit the question. I've not received an error message. The query runs without error and also without any results. But there are records, I know.

Comment: MJH - yes. I have tried to copy the entire date (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) from the previous query '>='.

Comment: @MJH - yes. I have tried to copy the entire date (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) from the previous query '>=. I've got the result 2018-01-01 09:28:57 from ">= query". I've tried "select date_field from mydb where datefield = '2018-01-01 09:28:57'. Nothing was listed.

Comment: Try SELECT Date_Field from mydb WHERE datefield between '2018-01-01 09:28:57' AND '2018-01-01 09:28:58'

Comment: @MJH, 'between' was fine! the results was listed. I can't understand why it doesn't show results using "=" or "like"...

Comment: '=' does not work because the value you are searching for is not EXACTLY equal to the value stored, the stored value will be something like '2018-0101 09:28:57.123' - notice the decimal at the end?

Comment: @MJH, you're completely right. I've forgot about that! I don't know if mysql and firebird stores these decimals, but I've never had this issue with them. But I should insist about 'LIKE'.. Shouldn't it work: ... like '2018%' instead '%2018%'?

Comment: LIKE is for comparing strings, I'm struggling to understand why you would want to, but you can cast/convert the date to a string and try it if you want.

Comment: @MJH, just for lazy! writing 'like 2018-01-01%' to get all records from this specific day, is 'costless' than write 'between 2018-01-01 00:00:00 and 2018-01-01 23:50:50'. Besides that, I agree with you about 'like' usage. I forgot about that because I have never had this issue with mysql or postgree. I did a little sql server 2000 server course about 10 years ago and since that, I just used mysql... and sometimes :). Lately I was invited to work with databases again and I'm working hard to refresh my brain and update myself! Thanks MJH! You are the best!

Comment: Voting to close as not-reproducible. The issue was simply that the equality comparisons never compared exact values (to the millisecond).

Comment: Although this was a very old post, it was queued up for my review. I am surprised nobody mentioned it at the time, but this behavior would occur if the `date_field` were a text type (such as `VARCHAR`) instead of a date/time type. **This was just bad database design.** Even worse, it appears that the data text was likely formatted as a MDY or DMY date.  (This would explain why '%2018%' matched, but '2018%' did not.) See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-gUjsnnB) for a demo of the stated behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to query DATETIME columns with LIKE statement. @MJH reminded me that this statement is used to compare strings. I've been doing this because I used to query on MySQL and there wasn't problems. Thanks @MJH!

After some reserch guided by @MJH advices, I've tired the following query:

```
select date_field from mydb where cast(date_field as DATE) = '2018-01-01';
```

I've got the desired results!

I'm going to ask DBeaver developers if it is a possible bug.

Thanks a lot!